# Pandas python: count number of services broken by month and state of project

Tags: python, pandas

I have this test dataset that shows the status of the services ('in_progress' or 'stopped') for every client, service_id and period of time. I wrote the code so you can copy and paste to generate the DataFrame. Let's see (ignore de left arrows for now):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: my_data = \
      [{'client_id' : '01', 'service_id': '01', 'status_start' : '2014-01-01', 'status_end' : '2014-02-13', 'service_status' : 'in_progress'},
       {'client_id' : '01', 'service_id': '02', 'status_start' : '2014-01-01', 'status_end' : '2014-02-18', 'service_status' : 'stopped'},
       {'client_id' : '01', 'service_id': '12', 'status_start' : '2014-02-14', 'status_end' : '2014-04-13', 'service_status' : 'in_progress'},
       {'client_id' : '02', 'service_id': '56', 'status_start' : '2014-03-01', 'status_end' : '2014-04-13', 'service_status' : 'in_progress'},
       {'client_id' : '02', 'service_id': '58', 'status_start' : '2014-02-04', 'status_end' : '2014-04-13', 'service_status' : 'stopped'},
       {'client_id' : '02', 'service_id': '60', 'status_start' : '2014-02-08', 'status_end' : '2014-04-23', 'service_status' : 'stopped'},
       {'client_id' : '03', 'service_id': '61', 'status_start' : '2014-02-10', 'status_end' : '2014-04-28', 'service_status' : 'in_progress'},
       {'client_id' : '03', 'service_id': '63', 'status_start' : '2014-02-01', 'status_end' : '2014-04-28', 'service_status' : 'in_progress'},
       {'client_id' : '03', 'service_id': '65', 'status_start' : '2014-01-10', 'status_end' : '2014-03-28', 'service_status' : 'in_progress'}
       ]
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(my_data)
In [4]: df

          client_id service_id  status_start    status_end  service_status
-->  0    01        01          2014-01-01      2014-02-13  in_progress
-->  1    01        02          2014-01-01      2014-02-18  stopped
-->  2    01        12          2014-02-14      2014-04-13  in_progress
     3    02        56          2014-03-01      2014-04-13  in_progress
     4    02        58          2014-02-04      2014-04-13  stopped
     5    02        60          2014-02-08      2014-04-23  stopped
     6    03        61          2014-02-10      2014-04-28  in_progress
     7    03        63          2014-02-01      2014-04-28  in_progress
-->  8    03        65          2014-01-10      2014-03-28  in_progress
```

The question I want to ask the data is: **how many services, per month and client, are in each service_status?**

That is, for example, client '01' in January had 1 service 'in_progress' and 1 'stopped'. That same client '01', in February had 2 'in_progress' (the one that already was in January and a new one in February) and 1 new one labeled as 'stopped'. But in March and April there was only one service 'in_progress' (services_ids '01' and '02' terminated in February). Following the same rule, client '03', in January, had 1 service 'in_progress' and 0 'stopped'.

So the final DataFrame would look like this (now you see arrows highlight rows for the examples just commented):

```
In [5]: summary_df

           client_id    month   status_in_progress  status_stopped
-->    0    01          Jan     1                   1
-->    1    01          Feb     2                   1
-->    2    01          Mar     1                   0
-->    3    01          Apr     1                   0
       4    02          Jan     0                   0
       5    02          Feb     0                   2
       6    02          Mar     1                   2
       7    02          Apr     1                   2
-->    8    03          Jan     1                   0
       9    03          Feb     3                   0
       10   03          Mar     3                   0
       11   03          Apr     2                   0
```

I tried to use `groupby` and `pivot_table`, but I was unsuccessful. Well, I must be honest: I used a `for` loop that took 6 hours to complete (the original dataset has more than 5 million rows).

Anybody can help? New to pandas/python, so be patient, please! :)

Thanks!

Comment: This is an interesting problem. And **thank you so much** for "I wrote the code so you can copy and paste to generate the DataFrame. " :D

Comment: I'm asking for help, so that's the least I can do :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new data set with one record per month, e.g. for this record:

```
          client_id service_id  status_start    status_end  service_status
-->  0    01        01          2014-01-01      2014-02-13  in_progress
```

we create these two records in the new data set:

```
          client_id service_id  month    service_status
          01        01          2014-01  in_progress
          01        01          2014-02  in_progress
```

and then group by client_id, month and service_status.

```
def month_id(s):
  """Convert YYYY-MM-DD to a month id"""
  y = int( s[0:4] )
  m = int( s[5:7] )
  return y*12 + m

def to_yyyymm(mid):
  """Convert a month id to YYYY-MM"""
  y = mid / 12
  m = mid % 12
  return "%04d-%02d" %  (y, m)

# Convert my_data to one record per month.

new_data = []
for r in my_data:
  mstart = month_id(r['status_start'])
  mend = month_id(r['status_end'])
  for mid in range(mstart, mend+1):
    m = to_yyyymm(mid)
    new_data.append( { 'client_id': r['client_id'], 'service_id': r['service_id'], 'service_status': r['service_status'], 'month': m } )

df = pd.DataFrame(new_data)
grouped = df.groupby(['client_id', 'month', 'service_status'])
for name, g in grouped:
  print name, len(g)
```

Output:

```
('01', '2014-01', 'in_progress') 1
('01', '2014-01', 'stopped') 1
('01', '2014-02', 'in_progress') 2
('01', '2014-02', 'stopped') 1
('01', '2014-03', 'in_progress') 1
('01', '2014-04', 'in_progress') 1
('02', '2014-02', 'stopped') 2
('02', '2014-03', 'in_progress') 1
('02', '2014-03', 'stopped') 2
('02', '2014-04', 'in_progress') 1
('02', '2014-04', 'stopped') 2
('03', '2014-01', 'in_progress') 1
('03', '2014-02', 'in_progress') 3
('03', '2014-03', 'in_progress') 3
('03', '2014-04', 'in_progress') 2
```

A missing record for a particular status means the count is zero for that client and month.

If the data is in a data frame, use `df.itertuples()` to iterate over the rows:

```
i_client_id = 1+df.columns.get_loc('client_id')
i_service_id = 1+df.columns.get_loc('service_id')
...
for r in df.itertuples():
  ... same code except replace r['client_id'] with r[i_client_id], etc.
```

Comment: Works great for my_data! What if the input is the DataFrame named df instead of the list my_data? I just added my_data so anybody could build the df.

Comment: Just updated it again - note the `1+` in the `.get_loc` calls.